# Dynamically changing mxml for UI description and state transition logic

Tags: apache-flex, flash, mxml

I want to use Adobe mxml to create a swf. However, the mxml gets compiled to swf itself and is not available after creating the swf. I want to [add states with UI components](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Flex/4.0/UsingFlashBuilder/WS6f97d7caa66ef6eb1e63e3d11b6c4d0d21-7fc6.html) without compiling it every-time. Is it possible with mxml? If not, what other design approaches can I take?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The very nature of MXML and ActionScript and the Flash Platform is that you must recompile the app every time you want to make change.  What you request is not possible.

There are a lot of things you can do--with ActionScript and MXML--to change the state of a component at run time based on some parameters.

As one example, when you click the down arrow button of a ComboBox the drop down will open.  This is, essentially, a run time state change.  There is no reason you can't perform the similar functionality with your own custom components.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that limitation. How can I do this (state transition logic addition and UI component - mainly button and text label addition) using custom components? Any examples?

Comment: @iceman For an example, open up the framework code for the Flex ComboBox and ComboBox skin and see how it does it.